# Adding Image Over Detected Rectangle

Tags: swift, core-image, cidetector

I'm using a `CIDetector` to detect a rectangle which i want to replace with a rectangular image.

The detection is working fine and i can draw an overlay over it, any idea how can i make the image fit and stick to all corners?

Here's the code:

```
 func drawHighlightOverlayForPoints(image: CIImage, topLeft: CGPoint, topRight: CGPoint,
                                     bottomLeft: CGPoint, bottomRight: CGPoint) -> CIImage {
    var overlay = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5))


    overlay = overlay.imageByCroppingToRect(image.extent)
    overlay = overlay.imageByApplyingFilter("CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent",
      withInputParameters: [
        "inputExtent": CIVector(CGRect: image.extent),
        "inputTopLeft": CIVector(CGPoint: topLeft),
        "inputTopRight": CIVector(CGPoint: topRight),
        "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(CGPoint: bottomLeft),
        "inputBottomRight": CIVector(CGPoint: bottomRight)
      ])
    return overlay.imageByCompositingOverImage(image)
  }
```

If i simply replace the overlay with a image, the image shows up very small and sticks to only one particular corner and doesn't fill the rect.

```
let testImage = UIImage(named: "card.jpg")

var overlayImage = CIImage(image: testImage!)
```

**Update:**

Using Simons project gives me the result i wanted,though the frame rate drops to less than 1 fps after a while, i do not know whats causing this might have been my implementation ?

```
  func newCameraImage(cameraCaptureHelper: CameraCaptureHelper, image: CIImage)
    {
        //halftone.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        if let rect = detector.featuresInImage(image).first as? CIRectangleFeature {

            perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(CGPoint:rect.topLeft),
                                          forKey: "inputTopLeft")
            perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(CGPoint:rect.topRight),
                                          forKey: "inputTopRight")
            perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(CGPoint:rect.bottomRight),
                                          forKey: "inputBottomRight")
            perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(CGPoint:rect.bottomLeft),
                                          forKey: "inputBottomLeft")


            perspectiveTransform.setValue(addImage,
                                          forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

            composite.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

            composite.setValue(perspectiveTransform.outputImage!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

            // let transformFinal = composite.outputImage

            imageView.image = composite.outputImage


        } else {

        imageView.image = image

        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/a-look-at-perspective-transform.html

Comment: Thanks Simon for your article, could this also be done in real time ?

Comment: No problem to run the CIFilters in real time, but I've found the detector to be a bit ropey when finding rectangles in video. 

Simon

Comment: Yeah noticed it, to make your article work with a live feed would i need to follow your steps and use the CISourceAtopCompositing filter? Should i just alter the code above to apply all the filters? I'm getting different results..

Comment: I have another project you may find useful: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CoreImageHelpers. `CameraCaptureHelper` wraps up all the code to capture live video and returns a stream of `CIImage`. You can then use the code in my first blog post.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: It worked though i have one more issue with the frame rate, see my update. Also do you cover it in any of your post or book how can i use the method on this project to create a video and save it to the library?  If you feel like composing an answer for your solution above and point to your post i'll mark it as accepted. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, sadly my book doesn't really cover that. By coincidence, I'm actually working on a project right now that saves filtered images to a new movie file and it's proved a challenge! Take a look at this: http://www.codegur.net/32822354/pics-to-movie-with-fade-transition

Comment: Also, take a look at this project which uses a face detector and runs pretty quickly: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CartoonEyes

I'll create a proper answer for this too....

Comment: I had to skip a feature in one of my apps since i couldn't create a movie file from all the filtered frames. Was still on the look out for that and ran again into it. So a step forward is good. Let me know or create a post if you find anything more. You're now officialy my go to guy for anything Core Image related 